# Как из проекта Qt сделать библиотеку?

Tags: c++, qt, dll

подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть проект на Qt с использованием qml-я, своеобразное приложение для работы с базой данных. Возникла необходимость воткнуть мой проект в другой, как небольшой кусок, решила сделать сабдирсом, но чего-то не получается, решила превратить весь свой проект в библиотеку... вопрос.. каким способом можно это сделать?

Comment: Какая система сборки используется? qmake/qbs/cmake/... ?

Comment: qmake вроде используется)

Comment: добавьте в проект, `TEMPLATE = lib
`

Comment: @PavelGridin , и весь проект станет библиотекой и ничего больше менять не нужно? все формы, окна все будет так же работать как и в проекте?

Comment: @Classic69, если нужна статическая библиотека, то нужно ещё добавить `CONFIG += staticlib`. Если же нужна динамическая то нужно описывать экспорт: функции и классы, см. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html. А так то да должно работать, ведь нет разницы откуда код берется.